# Wrapper scala API over Java API

Tags: java, scala, interface, future

I am new to Scala and I am building a Scala wrapper for my Java API

I have four Java Interfaces

```
public interface Client<T> {
 <T> Handle<T> execute(App<T> app);
}

public interface App<T> extends Serializable{
  T process(AppContext context) throws Exception;
}

public interface AppContext {
  File getDirectory();
  void deleteDirectory();
  File createDirectory(String path);
}

public interface Handle<T> extends Future<T> {
   static interface Listener<T> {          
       void onSuccess(Handle<T> handle)
       void onFailure(Handle<T> handle, Throwable e)
   }

   void addListener(Listener<T> listener);
}
```

Here are my Scala Equivalents

```
trait Process[T] extends Future[T] { 
  // Few abstract methods
}


class ProcessImpl[T](handle: Handle[T]) extends Process[T] {

val promise = Promise[T]

override def isCompleted: Boolean = ???

override def onComplete[U](func: (Try[T]) => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext)  = {
  case Success(t) => promise.success(handle.get())
  case Failure(e) => promise.failure(e)
   }

override def value: Option[Try[T]] = ???

@throws(classOf[Exception])
override def result(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): T = ???

@throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
@throws(classOf[TimeoutException])
override def ready(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait) = ???

 } 


class ScalaClient(javaClient: Client) {
   def execute[T](func: AppContext => T): ScalaHandle[T] = {
     val app = new App[T]
     @throws(classOf[Exception])
     override def process(AppContext context): T = func(context)

     val handle = javaClient.execute(app) // This returns a Handle obj. I want to convert it to ScalaHandle

    //My approach

     val scalahandle = new ProcessImpl(handle)       
     scalahandle
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)

Expected type was: Unit
      override def onComplete[U](func: (Try[T]) => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext) = {

Also, I want to know if my approach here is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't in `onComplete` *per se*—it's in the way you implement it.

```
override def onComplete[U](func: (Try[T]) => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext)  = {
  case Success(t) => promise.success(test.get())
  case Failure(e) => promise.failure(e)
}
```

Here, you define `onComplete` as a partial function from some function `Try[_] => U`—the type is not known, and it's definitely not overriding the original method, [`abstract def
onComplete[U](f: (Try[T]) ⇒ U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@onComplete[U](f:scala.util.Try[T]=>U)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit). Note that no `case` matches anything here: the `func` is not a `Try[T]` here.

As a side note, I cannot but mention that you should never ever extend a `Future`. A very useful motto is, *avoid inheritance at any cost.* In your case, I don't think inheritance wins you anything—rather, it adds to confusion.

What you probably are looking for is,

```
def asFuture[T](handle: Handle[T]): Future[T] = {
  val promise = Promise[T]()
  handle.addListener(new Handle.Listener[T] {
    def onSuccess(handle: Handle[T]) {
      promise.trySuccess(handle.get())
    }
    def onFailure(handle: Handle[T], e: Throwable) {
      promise.tryFailure(e)
    }
  })
  promise.future
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing clear information. I have edited my question. I need to have inheritance here to have a non blocking scala future for my API.

Comment: You don't _need to_, you just see it as a reasonable way. I would suggest you to write a function which takes a `Handle,` registers a listener on it, and when the underlying `Handle` is complete, completes a `Promise`. Now the only thing you return here is that `Promice`'s `.future`—no inheritance, no coupling.

Comment: But having it in onComplete would be an ideal Scala API. Though this can be done by adding listeners, I feel it's just not the scala way of doing it

Comment: It wouldn't; the `onComplete` is already provided by a `Future`, there's no need to implement a new one.

Comment: In the above code that you have posted should it be `promise.trySuccess(handle.get)`    ?? Because `Handle<T> extends JFuture`

Comment: Fair point, edited. If it helps, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: But I'll just see if someone can tell me the approach for implementing it in onComplete